# confused about macports

Tags: macos, macports

I am using MacBook Pro Mac OS 10.5 with related version of XCode. I am new to this development environment. I am learning macports, and I read information about macports from http://www.macports.org/. But I am still confused what macports is after reading information from this site.

I am previous working on Windows and Linux, could anyone let me know what macports is (in easy words) and what is the similar item on Windows/Linux?

thanks in avdance,
George

Comment: From your link: "The MacPorts Project is an open-source community initiative to design an easy-to-use *system for compiling, installing, and upgrading either command-line, X11 or Aqua based open-source software* on the Mac OS X operating system.", that tells it pretty clear, no? The closest thing in Windows would be MSI/Windows Update, I guess....

Comment: If it tells me it is similar to RPM, then I understand what it is. The words are good enough for an experienced user, but for a newbie, confused. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macports is a way of getting executables and other compiled code installed on your computer without having to work out the details of compiling/linking each apllication.

It is equivalent to a package manager under Linux and other Unicies. There is no direct equivalent under Windows.

Comment: I am confused about the term "port" in macports, does it mean macports install software package ported from other platform to mac OS?

Comment: Could I understand it as a software install/uninstall/manage platform/framework? Similar tool like RPM package manager on Linux?

Comment: ports is the BSD name for this sort of thing - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ports_collection

Comment: You mean both of them (comments)? How do you understand the term "ports"?

Comment: ports is I suppos short for 'something ported to this OS'

Comment: But from the wiki page you recommended, seems it means software package management platform?

Comment: Yes like a package manager (or perhaps the underpinings of a package manager) But in general it is the equivalent of RPM on Linux - the details differ

Answer (score 1):

It is just a convenient way to install a lot of *nix soft on your mac book. They are installed separately (not overwriting) from binaries/daemons/libs already installed on your mac (by default in folder /opl/local). Also they are much fresher than those installed on your mac.

For example 10.6 ships with bash 3.2, but after running `sudo port install bash`, you will get version 4.x (to make it your default shell add `/opt/local/bin/bash` to file `/private/etc/shells`, run `chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash` and reopen terminal).

Note other os x package managers: [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) and [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) ([superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/28529/macports-fink-etc))

Comment: Could I understand it as a software install/uninstall/manage platform/framework? Similar tool like RPM package manager on Linux?

Comment: I am confused about the term "port" in macports, does it mean macports install software package ported from other platform to mac OS?

Comment: How about your answer to my second comments? :-)

Comment: os x is *nix. And every port is a script telling which other ports should be installed, where to get source code and how to run make script (though not it is not always make :) ). Most ports are not ported, they are just compiled as on any other *nix system, though source code can contain conditional comments for mac os x